# Issues with stopping MediaPlayer

Tags: java, android, audio, android-mediaplayer

My application contains one mediaplayer with one (play/pause) button in audio.xml , but the problem is that I am not able to find right code to stop MediaPlayer before the page gets destroyed and because of that the app crashes when i log in audio page (xml) and quit without running mediaplayer , here is the code i used:

```
 public class audio extends Langue implements Runnable,

        OnClickListener, OnSeekBarChangeListener {
             private SeekBar seekBar;
             private Button startMedia;
            // private Button stopMedia;
         private MediaPlayer mp;


         @Override
         public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.audio);
          seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
          startMedia = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
          //stopMedia = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
          startMedia.setOnClickListener(this);
          //stopMedia.setOnClickListener(this);
          seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
          seekBar.setEnabled(false);


         }

         public void run() {
          int currentPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition();
          int total = mp.getDuration();

          while (mp != null && currentPosition < total) {
           try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            currentPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition();
           } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return;
           } catch (Exception e) {
            return;
           }
           seekBar.setProgress(currentPosition);
          }
         }

         public void onClick(View v) {
          if (v.equals(startMedia)) {
           if (mp == null) {
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.espoir);
            seekBar.setEnabled(true);
           }
           if (mp.isPlaying()) {
            mp.pause();
            startMedia.setText("Play");
           } else {
            mp.start();
            startMedia.setText("Pause");
            seekBar.setMax(mp.getDuration());
            new Thread(this).start();
           }
          }

         /*  if (v.equals(stopMedia) && mp != null) {
           if (mp.isPlaying() || mp.getDuration() > 0) {
            mp.stop();
            mp = null;
            startMedia.setText("Play");
            seekBar.setProgress(0);
           }
          }
*/
         }

         public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
           boolean fromUser) {
          try {
           if (mp.isPlaying() || mp != null) {
            if (fromUser)
             mp.seekTo(progress);
           } else if (mp == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Media is not running",
              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            seekBar.setProgress(0);
           }
          } catch (Exception e) {
           Log.e("seek bar", "" + e);
           seekBar.setEnabled(false);

          }
         }

         @Override
         public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                                           }

         @Override
         public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                                          }

         @Override
            public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case android.R.id.home:
                    this.finish();
                    return true;

                                          }
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
                                                                }
        // stop song
            @Override
            protected void onPause(){
             super.onPause();
             mp.stop();
            finish();
                                    } 


        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this into the onPause() method for preventing crash

```
try{
 mp.stop();
} catch(Exception e) {
}

finish();
```

Comment: it worked for me , no crash anymore, thank you very mush.